# Sieve of Eratosthenes for large numbers c++

Tags: c++, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Just like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954858/sieve-of-eratosthenes-algorithm), I also am working on the sieve of Eratosthenes. Also from the book *"programming principles and practice using c++"*, chapter 4. I was able to implement it correctly and it is functioning exactly as the exercise asks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned int amount = 0;

    cin >> amount;

    vector<int>numbers;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= amount; i++) {
        numbers.push_back(i);
    }

    for (unsigned int p = 2; p < amount; p++) {
        if (numbers[p] == 0)
            continue;

        cout << p << '\n';

        for (unsigned int i = p + p; i <= amount; i += p) {
            numbers[i] = false;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, how would I be able to handle real big numbers in the `amount` input? The `unsigned int` type should allow me to enter a number of 2^32=4,294,967,296. But I can't, I run out of memory. Yes, I've done the math: storing 2^32 amount of int, 32 bits each. So 32/8*2^32=16 GiB of memory. I have just 4 GiB...

So what I am really doing here is setting non-primes to zero. So I could use a boolean. But still, they would take 8 bits, so 1 byte each. Theoretical I could go to the limit for `unsigned int` (8/8*2^32=4 GiB), using some of my swap space for the OS and overhead. But I have a x86_64 PC, so what about numbers larger than 2^32?

Knowing that primes are [important in cryptography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439870/why-are-primes-important-in-cryptography), there must be a more efficient way of doing this? And are there also ways to optimize the time needed to find all those primes?

Answer (score 6):

In the sense of storage, you could use the `std::vector<bool>` container. Because of how it works, you have to trade in [speed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6782085/1816774) for storage. Because this implements one bit per boolean, your storage becomes 8 times as efficient. You should be possible to get numbers close to 8*4,294,967,296  if you have all your RAM available for this one program. Only thing you need to do, is use `unsigned long long` to unleash the availability of 64 bit numbers.

**Note**: Testing the program with the code example below, with an *amount* input of 8 billion, caused the program to run with a memory usage of approx. 975 MiB, proving the theoretical number.

You can also gain some time, because you can declare the complete vector at once, without iteration: `vector<bool>numbers (amount, true);` creates a vector of *size* equal to input *amount*, with all elements set to true. Now, you can adjust the code to set non-primes to **false** instead of 0.

Furthermore, once you have followed the *sieve* up to the square root of *amount*, all numbers that remain **true** are primes. Insert `if (p * p >= amount)` as an additional **continue** condition, just after you output the prime number. Also this is a humble improvement for your processing time.

**Edit**: In the last loop, `p` can be squared, because all numbers until the square of `p` are already proved not to be primes by previous numbers.

All together you should get something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned long long amount = 0;

    cin >> amount;

    vector<bool>numbers (amount, true);

    for (unsigned long long p = 2; p < amount; p++) {
        if ( ! numbers[p])
            continue;

        cout << p << '\n';

        if (p * p >= amount)
            continue;

        for (unsigned long long i = p * p; i <= amount; i += p) {
            numbers[i] = false;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you start cycle from i=p*p in the last loop?

Comment: No, that would square the numbers. Imagine the first loop is at p=3. Then i=3*3 = 9. This would skip 6. Wait... that has been put on false by 2 already. Let me think about p=5. then i=25. 10 is already false'd by 2 and 15 by 3. I _think_ you are right, I will check

Comment: Yes, program outputs exactly the same numbers, but it increases the speed. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You've asked a couple of different questions.

For primes up to 2**32, sieving is appropriate, but you need to work in segments instead of in one big blog. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249378/segmented-sieve-of-eratosthenes) tells how to do that.

For cryptographic primes, which are very much larger, the process is to pick a number and then test it for primality, using a probabilistic test such as a Miller-Rabin test or a Baillie-Wagstaff test. This process isn't perfect, and occasionally a composite might be chosen instead of a prime, but such an occurrence is very rare.

Comment: If I understand correctly, segments removes the memory limits I'm hitting. So it would be possible to come close to 2^64? (Which would be significantly more then the limits I have now).

Comment: It removes the limit on the size of the sieve. But you must also either pre-compute and store the sieving primes, or compute them on the fly. It is possible to sieve to 2**64, but difficult. You might find [this page](http://sweet.ua.pt/tos/software/prime_sieve.html) interesting.